# Docker container transfer using LFS properties

Tags: docker

Hello Docker Mariners,

I'm working on the final work of the computer engineering course, and I'm having some problems.

Correct me if I misunderstand this docker structure:

An image / container is created using the layering system. So there is a division between the system, applications, files, etc. The changes are getting in the upper layers, by the LFS access logic.

Look at this image:

[image: 1]

Docker works like this, right?

Now imagine that you need to send a container / image to another host. There are options for export, save, import, etc ... However, in all of them a giant file is generated. With the complete system.

Is there a way to make this transfer only with the differences?

Let's say I created a container based on Ubuntu, I inserted a text file inside it. So I'd like to transfer it to another host, this host have the ubuntu image, sending it again would be unnecessary. Is there a way to see that only one file has changed and only transfer this layer? The transfer would be some KB and not MB.

Thank you

Comment: +1 for Mariners. Things work as you expect, but for the first image push, regardless of that server already has or not the base image. Following pushes only push KB as you stated (I work every day viewing that fact)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I'm doing something wrong. Can you explain better how this transference takes place? Using save and import, he always sends everything. To send only this extra layer is it necessary to use the Docker Hub?

Comment: How are you sending? `docker push`? Also, try `docker history <image-id>` in each image to see the layers size in MB

Comment: I was using docker save and import (with a tar.gz file). Now that I realized how much I was traveling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either create an account on Docker Hub (if you don't mind the image being public) or set up a Docker Registry to push images to.

If you opt for Docker Hub, then you don't need to push anything if you link it to GitHub with automated builds.

If you opt for your own Registry, here are the details:
https://docs.docker.com/registry/